# Zoom-in in world map in R

Tags: r, maps

I am using the following code to draw map of specific countries:

```
library(maps)
library(mapdata)
map('worldHires',
    c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight', 'Wales:Anglesey'))
```

This produces the following image:

[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2XcR.png)

How to zoom-in to this? This image doesn't help. Also, the map doesn't look realistic. Is there some way to make it look more realistic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (legacy) worldHires set has all islands that belong (in some way or another) to the UK, named "UK:...". So this includes Gibraltar, but also even much more distant islands (like the Pitcairns). You can see all included polygons by

```
map('worldHires',
         c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight', 'Wales:Anglesey'))$names
```

The simplest way to get rid of these remote places, is to set boundaries:

```
map('worldHires',
     c('UK', 'Ireland', 'Isle of Man','Isle of Wight', 'Wales:Anglesey'),
 xlim=c(-15,5),ylim=c(48,61))
```

this will reduce the number of polygons from 39 to the 31 that you would expect.

Alternatively, you can list all parts explicity ("UK:Scotland","UK:Jersey" etc) or eliminate the remote parts of the UK explicitely. e.g.
'UK:(?!Gib|Asc)' would fit UK:... except Gibraltar and Ascension island. but there are a few more.